# How to change UINavigationController background color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar

I'm able to change the backgroung image of `UINavigationController` by overriding drawRect: method:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navController.png"];
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
        self.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}

@end
```

the background is what I intended to be and the `tintColor` as well, but when trying to set a color that isn't existing in `UIColor` class it fails and shows strange color:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navController.png"];
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
        self.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(26/255) green:(103/255) blue:(159/255)                      alpha:1];
}

@end
```

How can I force `UINavigationBar` to show the color I want?

**Note:** I'm only having a problem with navigation controller buttons color since the background itself is set to image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
self.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(26.0f/255.0f) green:(103.0f/255.0f) blue:(159.0f/255.0f) alpha:1.0f];
```

Otherwise you're doing integer arithmetic and you'll end up with 0 for all of them probably. Use floating point arithmetic and you get the values you desire.

Answer (score 8):

This Works for me

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:57.0/255.0 green:158.0/255 blue:209.0/255 alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

> navigationController.view.backgroundColor = .yourColor